# GPU Stream processors meaning

Tags: gpu

I came across this term "GPU stream processors" on http://yourultimatepc.com/ when reading about how to pick parts for a build I am doing and I just want to know more about them and how they affect the performance of GPUs.

Thanks

Comment: What do you not understand from reading the results from https://www.google.com/search?q=GPU+stream+processors?

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/928460/confused-about-gpu-having-hundreds-of-processors-inside-it/928476#928476

Answer (score 1):

This is probably extremely oversimiplified.  I welcome corrections and additional information.

Modern GPUs support shaders.  Shaders are small programs.  When a GPU is filling in a polygon or other primitive, instead of simply turning on a pixel, it can run a small program for that pixel.  The program can decide the "shade" of the pixel, or flip on/off additional pixels, or other things.  This allows a wide variety of effects.

A stream processor is the entity that runs the shader programs.  Stream processors do not have to be used to "shade" polygons per se, this is the basis of GPGPU/CUDA/using your GPU for things other than graphics.

You need a bunch of them running at the same time since the GPU is trying to draw a frame as fast as possible.  The more there are and the faster they are, the better.